# Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Xml.Linq.XElement)' is not queryable

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, smart-device

My class gives me an error:

`Error  4   Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Xml.Linq.XElement)' is not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for the LINQ provider.`

I searched similar questions and found out it may be problem with imports/references. However, I think I imported everything I need and it still gives me the error.

The class and project references are below:

[image: references]

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Data
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq


Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

    Dim Result As Integer
    Dim mxldDataParams As System.Xml.Linq.XDocument = XDocument.Load("mypath\myxml.xml")


    Private Function GetProcedureName(ByVal Name As String) As String
        Dim Result As String = String.Empty
        'this line gives the error
        Dim Elems As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From Elem As XElement In mxldDataParams.Root.Elements Where Elem.Name.LocalName = "data" And Elem.@name = Name
        For Each Elem As XElement In Elems
            Result = Elem...<target>...<remote>...<source>.@name
            Exit For
        Next
        Return Result
    End Function


End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have an import for `System.Linq`, which means the compiler can't find LINQ to Objects, which is the LINQ implementation you're trying to use.

Just add this to your imports:

```
Imports System.Linq
```

LINQ to XML isn't really a LINQ provider - it's just an XML API which also works well with LINQ to Objects.